# How to use AngularJs with Laravel 5.2 as laravel blading template and angular directive have same tags {{}}

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have read many blogs relating to this and have tried for almost a week but unable to use the both together.
Also let me tell you I have also tried using angular Js with @{{}} and also by changing the tags of angular through interpolate on module initialization.So please suggest any other method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your blade code simply add `@` to Angular braces.

Example:

`@{{name}}`

This tells blade not to parse or treat the braces as blade code but to ignore the braces and simply output

`{{name}}`

Read Blade section in Laravel documentation for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can change angular syntax using $interpolationProvider:

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```

Or change blade template configuration using Blade facade

```
Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>'); 
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%%', '%%>');
```

One of these stragegy will be mandatory if you are using blade and angular

Answer (score 0):

You'd better re-think of your app structure and use Laravel for WebServices only.

Comment: Why should Laravel used for only Web services?